# Calculate safe amount of items for weighted random picks

Tags: probability, statistics, random

Say I want to create lootboxes of 5 random items, weighted by rarity: common, rare, epic.

Given I've got 10 unique common items, 6 rare items and 3 epic with weights: 0.7 (common), 0.2 (rare) and 0.1 (epic) and I want to create the items upfront to allow the creation of 1000 lootboxes. Also, I need to guarantee that any lootboxes will have at least 1 rare items.

What would be the formula to calculate how many items of each I need to create so I don't fall short of items when creating the lootboxes?

The "brute force" way would be to create at least the maximum amount of each item those lootboxes might have if the random process returned always the same item in the class. But is there a way to optimize it?

Comment: This is not clear.  First of all, if each box contains $2$ rare items out of $5$, then $40\%$ of the items are rare, contradicting your probabilities.  Secondly, are you assigning things randomly or do you want to adhere to precise quotas?

Comment: You're right, I've updated the question to be at least 1 rare item. I'm randomly assigning items but I need the ability to guarantee some items will always be created, even though I might have other settings where, for instance, 1 epic or 2 rares are guaranteed.

Comment: But if the other items are generated randomly, then there can be no guarantee that you'll have enough unless you have enough to cover the worst case (since the worst case is, after all, possible).  So, you either need to make enough for the worst case or you need to restric your choices.

Comment: I see. As I'm not familiar with statistics and probability I thought there could be a way to make at least an educated guess...

Comment: Deal with the rare ones first, so now you need $4000$ objects, each of which has a $\frac 78$ chance of being ordinary and a $\frac 18$ chance of being epic.  Now, two suggestions:  First suggestion, just create $\frac 78\times 4000$ ordinary ones and $\frac 18\times 4000$ epic ones and assign those to boxes uniformly at random.

Comment: Second suggestion:  Just make enough to cover your chances up to $95\%$ probability or whatever.  That would leave you with a $5\%$ (or whatever) chance of needing to make more, but you'd probably be ok.

Comment: Thanks @lulu. I think I'll stick to the worst case approach as it's cheaper to pre-create items than creating them at runtime. Cheers!